# Ext JS 4 : How to create a string that contains the code of a specific object allready created?

Tags: javascript, extjs

i need to code a app that will create widgets, this is; adding childrens to a container in runtime.

I need a way to read the code of the created widget so i can store it in a database as a string (i guess it's the best way since afterwards using eval() may do the trick to load the stored widgets).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think you can do that, or extremely inefficient.

The best way would be to determine what kind of data you would need to store in order to re-create it back from simple configuration.

For example, I have a Blog system, and in it we have 4 different set of widgets, namely `TextWidget`, `RSSWidget`, `BlogRollWidget`, `MetaWidget`

All of these widgets inherited from a base class `Widget` and organized by a parent class called `Widgets`. This `Widgets` class will then have the ability to read raw configuration and re-create the widgets base on the `type`, as well as some other data as needed by each individual widgets.

Such configuration string could be something like this:

```
{
    widgets: [{
        type: 'text',
        x: 30,
        y: 80,
        text: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
    },{
        type: 'blogroll',
        x: 60,
        y: 120,
        links:[{
            title: 'Google',
            link: 'http://www.google.com'
        }]
    },{
        type: 'meta',
        x: 80,
        y: 60
    }]
}
```

So in a way that you have the ability to recreate different type of widgets base on the configuration, and at the same time you can simply `stringify` it and save it in your database.